# One night in a traditional temple in Japan

Tags: japan, accommodation, religion

I'm planing to go to Japan in April.

After some research I decided to sleep just in Tokyo and Kyoto.

My wife and I are planning to stay in a hotel similar an IBIS or Formule 1, a simple place only to sleep.

I'm reserving one night to sleep in a traditional Japanese Temple. My question is where is the best place to do it, near Tokyo or near Kyoto?

Comment: I used to get [Formule 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotel_Formule_1) and [Formula One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_One) mixed up as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the most beautiful place to temple lodging is [Koyasan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_K%C5%8Dya) which is close to Kyoto. Different temples offer lodging with a traditional meal included. They also offer the opportunity to pray with the monks early in the morning (5 a.m.) and before dinner.
In order to reach Koyasan from Kyoto you have to take a train to Osaka (Namba station) and from there take another train Nankai Koya to Gokurakubashi and finally take a spectacular cable car to the mount :-) It's quite a trip but I belive it's totally worth it.

I went there this summer and it was a really awesome, especially the graveyard. Temple lodging in Koyasan it's quite expensive (around 14000 yen each) tho. They ask you to book one week in advance, at least, but I manage to get there with a one day notice by asking the hostel's staff in Kyoto to call them, usually if someone can speak Japanese it's far easier to overcome these little problems :-)

You may also wanto to visit the [Official tourism site](http://eng.shukubo.net/)

Comment: +1, beat me to posting this -- Koya-san is great.  It's not super-close to Kyoto though, it's >3 hours by train.  However, if you're coming in via Kansai Airport, it's considerably closer to Osaka.

Answer (score 2):

Koya-san is the ultimate overnight temple experience, and accommodates English-speakers easier than anywhere in Japan.

However, if it is too far out of the way, [Myoshin-ji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My%C5%8Dshin-ji) in Kyoto also permits overnight stays.  Temples in Kamakura, about an hour south of downtown Tokyo, do as well.